# Find N-th most occurring keys in map

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, dictionary, performance

I have a map that contains different strings and how many times they occur. I want to find the N-th most occurring keys and order them in a descending order. Is there a STL function that can do this? And if not what is an efficient way to do this in a map container?

Data structure:

```
map<string, unsigned int>
```

Here is a sample of my map:

[image]

Comment: You're in luck, all keys in a map occur only once.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Well, the value says how many times the key occurs in my application.

Comment: [std::partial_sort_copy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/partial_sort_copy/) may help.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore There is also STL multimap that allows duplicate keys, but map allows only unique keys.

Answer (score 2):

Following may help:

```
struct comp
{
    using P = std::pair<const std::string, std::size_t>;
    bool operator() (const P&lhs, const P& rhs) const
    {
        return rhs.second < lhs.second;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const std::map<std::string, std::size_t> m = {{"a", 1}, {"b", 4}, {"c", 2}};
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::size_t>> res(2);

    std::partial_sort_copy (begin(m), end(m), begin(res), end(res), comp());

    for (const auto& e : res) {
        std::cout << e.first << " " << e.second << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
b 4
c 2
```

Comment: @TemplateRex: I need to remove the `const` from key `std::string` in the `std::pair`...

Comment: I copied your code and tried it in MCVS2012 premium with these headers: #include <map>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>, but still getting a lot of errors. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have time to post working code but here is the thing you can do :
1) you can make another multimap < int , string >
2) use vector< pair >

but these will take very much space if there are **many elements**. so , **efficient** approach should be :

> I want to find the N-th most occurring keys and order them in a descending order.

If `N` is **NOT large** , better is to create a **heap** of size `N` , where each node will contain pair> .